# How do you install mysql-connector-python (development version) through pip?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a virtualenv in which I am running Django 1.8 with Python 3.4

I am trying to get support for MySQL however I am having trouble getting the different connectors to work. I have always used mysql-connector-python with django 1.7 and would like to continue using it.

The development version of mysql-connector-python (2.1.2) seems to have support for Django 1.8 now.

How do I install the development version using pip install (within my virtualenv)? I have tried running the following command:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python==2.1.2 --allow-external mysql-connector-python
```

but the 2.1.2 developer version is not available there:

```
could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-connector-python==2.1.2 (from versions: 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4)
  Some insecure and unverifiable files were ignored (use --allow-unverified mysql-connector-python to allow).
No matching distribution found for mysql-connector-python==2.1.2
```

I have tried downloading the file directly from: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

...but for some reason after installation the connector is not available within my virtualenv

Help please :-) Thank you.
'

**EDIT:** 
I have tried 
`pip install mysql-python` but it is not supported by Python 3.4

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I agree, the debian packages appear to be broken for at least Ubuntu 14.04.

The apt-get version and the pip version do not include the 2.1.x releases.

To get it done, I had to grab the source:

```
$  git clone https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python.git
$  cd mysql-connector-python
$  python ./setup.py build
$  sudo python ./setup.py install

...

>>> import mysql.connector as msc
>>> msc.__version__
'2.1.3'
>>>
```

Comment: This seems to work in my virtualenv on OSX as well. Thanks.